# NSLog statement to see if image exist to save to photo album

Tags: iphone, ios6, nslog

Want to check if image0.png, image1.png, image2.png , image3.png, image4.png really exist.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<=61; i++) {
         NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
         UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

How to write NSLog statement to check if image0.png, image1.png, image2.png , image3.png, image4.png really exist. Every time it is saving only image0.png image.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but for logical decisions and branching it's better to use an `if()` statement instead of calling `NSLog()`...

Comment: when i debug in LLDB by adding breakpoint at statement UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil); and do po uiimage it shows no result. That is the reason i want to check with NSLog statement

Answer (score 0):

You still can use NSFileManager's fileExistsAtPath method to check whether the file does really exist or not.

[UIImage imageNamed:] loads the image from the application bundle. So, if the file is already is the bundle and has right name as what you're invoking, then it should have been loaded. Try deleting the application from your device/simulator and reload it again. Also, make sure that all of your bitmaps are copied to the bundle by checking the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase of your target.

Another remark: it is useless to load the UIImage into a UIImageView before saving it to the library, unless you need that for some other processing... So this line of code may be redundant:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

And the last line will become:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Hope this helps ;)